# List just the permissions of a file

Tags: permissions, ls

I want to know how to just check for the permission of a file.

I know

```
ls -l yourfile
```

will show you it but I just need the nine permission letters.

Thanks

Comment: It doesnt give what I'm asking, I'm just asking for the nine letter permission not the whole content and I need to use ls

Comment: I am asking for help...

Comment: You *need* to use `ls`? Then you can do `ls > /dev/null | stat -c %A *`.

Answer (score 0):

A comment suggests a possible duplicate, but the accepted answer is nonportable.  Portably:

```
ls -ld file |awk '{ print $1; }'
```

or

```
ls -ld file |sed -e 's/ .*//'
```

I added the `-d` option to avoid surprise if *"file"* happens to be a *directory*.

Longstanding habit for configure scripts makes me prefer the latter, which is not always a few characters shorter.